# Let $S$ a free system and $T$ a generating system of $V$. If $S ⊆ T$, there exists a basis of $V$ called $β$ with $S ⊆ β ⊆ T$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I have to prove the following proposition:

$V$ is a space which finite dimension. We also have $S$, which is a free system; and $T$, a generating system of $V$. If $S ⊆ T$, there exists a basis of $V$ called $β$ where:
$$S ⊆ β ⊆ T.$$
I understand what the proposition is saying. I know that $\dim V=n$ for example. As $S$ is a free system I know that $\dim S$ would be smaller that $\dim V$ or equal. I also know that if $T$ is the generating system of $V$, $\dim T$ will be bigger than $\dim V$ or equal. But I don't really knowhow to create a solid proof.

Comment: You should mean $|S|\leq\dim V$ and $|T|\geq\dim V$. Cardinality, not dimension.

Comment: But in this case is not the same the cardinality and the dimensions? Wich are the diferences?